# Mesa 17.0.1 says OpenGL Core 4.5 even though my Intel HD 520 Graphics Card supports only 4.4

Tags: c++, opengl, gpu, intel

When I query some `OpenGL` info then I get the following statements:

```
Vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center
WindowManager: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2) 
OpenGL version: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 17.0.1
GLSL version: 4.50
```

But my laptop CPU/GPU **Intel 6200U with Intel HD 520 (Ubuntu 17.04)** supports according to [Intel Product Specification](http://ark.intel.com/products/88193/Intel-Core-i5-6200U-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-2_80-GHz) only `OpenGL 4.4`.

Can anybody say something about this? Is the OpenGL query wrong?
Thanks

Comment: report it as a bug to the devs

Comment: I'm guessing the Intel spec refers to support at the hardware/firmware level.  I'm not that familiar with the differences between OpenGL 4.4 and 4.5 but if it's not *that* much then there's at least a possibility the new features could be implemented via software by the driver.  Have you tried creating a 4.5 context?

Comment: @G.M. I have not but I will do it later. It might also be confused with the extensions in 4.4 and so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the open source driver on non-Windows platforms, it is very possible for it to support a higher OpenGL version than the Intel-created driver. Intel isn't exactly known for keeping their GL stuff up-to-date.

Requesting a 4.5 context in your program should prove what your currently installed drivers can provide.

Comment: Answer from bugzilla (https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=100257) to my question for Mesa: "That's because the Intel website is out-of-date.  Sky Lake GPUs support OpenGL 4.5 just fine.  Welcome to the future! :-)". So thread closed then